# Flutter http get request json serialization

Tags: android, json, flutter, http-get

I would like to make a get requests and to convert results to a list of objects.
Actually i did that :

post_model.dart

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Post {

  Post({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PostFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PostToJson(this);

  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
 
}
```

http_service.dart :

```
class HttpService {
  final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  final String postsURL = '/posts';
  final Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };


  List<Post> parsePosts(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }


  Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts() async {

    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.https(url, postsURL));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return compute(parsePosts,response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load posts ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }


}
```

But i encouter all in red on the parsePosts method.
On the final parsed :

```
Missing variable type for 'parsed'.
Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file.dart(implicit_dynamic_variable)
```

and on the return :

```
A value of type 'dynamic' can't be returned from the method 'parsePosts' because it has a return type of 'List<Post>'
```

I just don't understand what i'm doing wrong, because i have follow the flutter doc here :
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I did this code for that API:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';


class Post {
  int? userId, id;
  String? title, body;

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    userId = data['userId'];
    id = data['id'];
    title = data['title'];
    body = data['body'];
  }
}

class JsonPlaceHolder {
  static const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static FutureOr<void> _doGet(String path, {void doThis(var response)?}) async {
    await HttpReqService.getJson(baseUrl + path)
      .then((response) => doThis == null ? print(response) : doThis(response))
      .whenComplete(() => print('\nFetching done!'));
  }
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static FutureOr<void> _doPost(String path, {required Object body, int okCode = 200}) async {
    await HttpReqService.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(baseUrl + path, body: body, okCode: okCode)
      .then((response) => print(response))
      .whenComplete(() => print('\nPost sent successfully'));
  }
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static FutureOr<void> fetchPosts({int? id, bool onlyComments = false, bool useObjList = false}) async {
    var path = '/posts/${id ?? ''}';
    if (id != null && onlyComments) path += '/comments';
    useObjList 
      ? await _doGet(path, doThis: (response) {
        if (response != null) {
          print((response as List).map<Post>((m) => Post.fromJson(m as Map<String, dynamic>)));
        }
      }) 
      : await _doGet(path);
  }
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static FutureOr<void> fetchComments([int? postId]) => _doGet('/comments${postId != null ? '?postId='+postId.toString() : ''}');
  static FutureOr<void> fetchAlbums() => _doGet('/albums');
  static FutureOr<void> fetchPhotos() => _doGet('/photos');
  static FutureOr<void> fetchTodos() => _doGet('/todos');
  static FutureOr<void> fetchUsers() => _doGet('/users');
}


void main(List<String> args) async {
  // await JsonPlaceHolder.fetchComments(1);
  await JsonPlaceHolder.fetchPosts(useObjList: true);
  print('Finished!');
}
```

Result:

```
(Instance of 'Post', Instance of 'Post', Instance of 'Post', ..., Instance of 'Post', Instance of 'Post')

Fetching done!
Finished!
```

**Note**

- `wnetworking` package is not ready to publish yet, it contains operations related to API, etc. You can replace `HttpReqService.getJson` and `HttpReqService.post` with your typical `http.get` and `http.post` respectively but keep in mind the return value and exceptions.
- Use `Uri.parse`

Comment: Hello, thanks, but no, i want to follow the doc, that should work if they have published it

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are due to a dart version.

A fix has been made by another user on github : https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/5798

Following this PR, it's works